# When i am trying to Connect jmeter remotely through my Java code (non-gui jmeter), am getting an error

Tags: java, jmeter, remote-access, jmeter-plugins

I am trying to Connect jmeter remotely through my Java code (non-gui jmeter), but I am getting an error: rconfigure() method java.rmi.UnmarshalException

Here is my Code:

```
public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {

    // Set jmeter home path
    File jmeterHome = new File("E:\\apache-jmeter-3.2");

    if (jmeterHome.exists()) {

        // Inserting the properties of Jmeter.

        File jmeterProperties = new File(
                "E:\\apache-jmeter-3.2\\bin\\jmeter.properties");
        if (jmeterProperties.exists()) {
            // Creating JMeter Engine

            StandardJMeterEngine jmeter = new StandardJMeterEngine();
            // JMeter initialization (properties, log levels, locale, etc)

            JMeterUtils.setJMeterHome(jmeterHome.getPath());
            JMeterUtils.loadJMeterProperties(jmeterProperties.getPath());

            // you can comment this line out to see extra log messages of
            // i.e DEBUG level

            JMeterUtils.initLogging();
            JMeterUtils.initLocale();

            // JMeter Test Plan, basically JOrphan HashTree
            HashTree testPlanTree = new HashTree();

            // First HTTP Sampler
            HTTPSamplerProxy sampler = new HTTPSamplerProxy();
            sampler.setDomain("https://google.com/");
            sampler.setPort(8080);
            sampler.setPath("/");
            sampler.setMethod("GET");

            sampler.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS,
                    HTTPSamplerProxy.class.getName());

            sampler.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS,
                    HttpTestSampleGui.class.getName());

            // Loop Controller
            LoopController loopController = new LoopController();
            loopController.setLoops(10);
            loopController.setFirst(true);
            loopController.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS,
                    LoopController.class.getName());
            loopController.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS,
                    LoopControlPanel.class.getName());
            loopController.initialize();

            // InterleaveControler

            // InterleaveControl controller = new InterleaveControl();

            // Thread Group
            ThreadGroup threadGroup = new ThreadGroup();
            threadGroup.setName("Sample Thread Group");
            threadGroup.setNumThreads(100);
            threadGroup.setRampUp(10);
            threadGroup.setSamplerController(loopController);
            threadGroup.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS,
                    ThreadGroup.class.getName());
            threadGroup.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS,
                    ThreadGroupGui.class.getName());

            // Test Plan
            TestPlan testPlan = new TestPlan("Test planing");
            testPlan.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS,
                    TestPlanGui.class.getName());
            testPlan.setUserDefinedVariables((Arguments) new ArgumentsPanel()
                    .createTestElement());

            // Construct Test Plan from previously initialized elements
            testPlanTree.add(testPlan);
            HashTree threadGroupHashTree = testPlanTree.add(testPlan,
                    threadGroup);
            threadGroupHashTree.add(sampler);

            // save generated test plan to JMeter's .jmx file format
            SaveService.loadProperties();
            SaveService.saveTree(testPlanTree, new FileOutputStream(
                    "E:\\JunitJArs\\junitjunitjmeter_api.csv"));

            // add Summarizer output to get test progress in stdout like:
            // summary = 2 in 1.3s = 1.5/s Avg: 631 Min: 290 Max: 973 Err: 0
            // (0.00%)

            Summariser summer = null;
            String summariserName = JMeterUtils.getPropDefault(
                    "summariser.name", "summary");
            if (summariserName.length() > 0) {
                summer = new Summariser(summariserName);
            }

            // Store execution results into a .jtl file, we can save file as
            // csv also

            String reportFile = "C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Jmeter\\new\\report.jtl";
            String csvFile = "C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Jmeter\\new\\report.csv";

            ResultCollector logger = new ResultCollector(summer);
            logger.setFilename(reportFile);

            ResultCollector csvlogger = new ResultCollector(summer);
            csvlogger.setFilename(csvFile);

            testPlanTree.add(testPlanTree.getArray()[0], logger);
            testPlanTree.add(testPlanTree.getArray()[0], csvlogger);

            // Run Test Plan

            List<JMeterEngine> engines = new LinkedList<>();
            Properties remoteProps = new Properties();

            DistributedRunner distributedRunner = new DistributedRunner(
                    remoteProps);

            List<String> hosts = new LinkedList<>();

            // adding JMeter slaves here

            hosts.add("172.16.104.199");


            distributedRunner.setStdout(System.out);
            distributedRunner.setStdErr(System.err);

            distributedRunner.init(hosts, testPlanTree);


            engines.addAll(distributedRunner.getEngines());
            distributedRunner.start();

            // jmeter.configure(testPlanTree);
            // / jmeter.run();
            System.err.println("Your Test excuted");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
    System.err.println("Jmeter properties error");
    System.exit(1);
}
```

in console its showing

> -Configuring remote engine: 172.16.104.199
>
> Starting remote engines
>
> Starting the test @ Wed Jun 28 17:45:07 IST 2017 (1498652107364) Error in rconfigure() method java.rmi.UnmarshalException

I have tried to search it but didn't get any proper solution

Comment: I am new to jmeter if any needfull given.

Comment: can you give full stack trace of error ?

Comment: @user7294900 i am getting this everytime 
Configuring remote engine: 172.16.104.160
Connection refused to host: 172.16.104.160; nested exception is: 
 java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
Failed to configure 172.16.104.160
Exception in thread "main" Stopping remote engines
Remote engines have been stopped
java.lang.RuntimeException: Following remote engines could not be configured:[172.16.104.160]
 at org.apache.jmeter.engine.DistributedRunner.init(DistributedRunner.java:112)
 at withRemote.Remoteee.main(Remoteee.java:187)

Answer (score 0):

It can happen if the jdk version on client is different than server
see in [Post](http://www.jmeter-archive.org/Remote-Testing-Problem-td513138.html)

Comment: I have tried using same java version & jmeter version , but again getting the same issue .
Can you tell me what properties (key & value) we have to pass in distributedrunner .